# Is it possible to ignore/drop key input events in a Node.js CLI app (readline)

Tags: node.js, readline

I am writing a cli app that responds to questions, using the readline module.
I wish to prohibit the use of the tab key.

I can 'listen' for the key event, but that doesnt stop the key event from being processed.

Is there a way to divert or dismiss key events?

```
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
  if(chunk !== null) {
    console.log('data: '+chunk);
  }
}).on('keypress', function(char, key) {
  if (key.name === "tab") {
    console.log('action to drop/ignore key here?');
  }
});
```

Comment: Unlikely that you could solve this 100% of the time, but if the action you want to eliminate is the presence of a tab character (`\t`) in the input, then you could just filter those out after the fact?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand 'after the fact', this will result in the tab indent still being shown to the user, right?
In my case that would be at rl.on('line', (input) => { process_input(); })

Comment: Yeah... I just meant in the input you read in. Not sure you can stop the CLI input itself using stdin

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case.
Thank you for your reply nonetheless, I won't put any more time/effort into it!